# Get Checkbox[] values in javascript for php

Tags: php, javascript, checkboxlist

I am having an issue getting the values checked in the check-box.  I have tried to clean up the code.

I have been able to get the all the selected check-boxes selected (not per row) or i can get the check-box id per row but not the selected value.   I am pretty sure I can transfer the values to the another page but do not know how to get them.

Any assistance here would greatly be appreciated!

```php
 //php variables used
 $pages = 2
 $size = 4
```

```html
  <form id="form" name="cb">
  <div style=" width:800px; height:500px; overflow:auto">
  <h2>Select Editions</h2>
  <table id='table' name='table' border=1 cellpadding=7 width=50% height=50% align='center'>\n
```

```php
    for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++) :
      print "<td id='page_$x' class='page_button' align='center' custom='0' >Page $x - ";
        for($i = 1; $i <= $size; $i++) :
          print "<input type='checkbox' class='ebutton' id='etype_$x' name='checks[]' value='$i' /> $i";
        endfor;
```

```html
      </td>
      </tr>
```

```php
    //php end for loop
    endfor;
```

```html
  </div>
  </form>
```

Here is the Javascript that updates based on the class of the checkbox class

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".ebutton").change(function() {

        var idp = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
        var page_num = idp[1];

        //  I need to find out how to get the checkboxes that are checked per row. Ex: 01,02
        //var editions = ?;
        //alert(editions);

        var hidden_id = "#etype_page_" + page_num;
          if($(hidden_id).length < 1) {
            $("#base").append('<input type="hidden" id="etype_page_'+ page_num +'" name="'+ page_num +'"  value="'+ editions +'" class="hidden_edtype" custom="' + editions +'">');
          } else {
            $(hidden_id).val($(this).val());
          }
        update_eShow();
      });
    });

    function update_eShow() {
      $("#eShow").html('');
        $(".hidden_edtype").each(function() {
         var page = $(this).attr("name");
         var value = $(this).attr("custom");
         $("#eShow").append('page:' + page + ' values:' + value +'<br>');
      });
    }
```

page looks like this:

### | Page 1 -  []1 []2 []3 []4 |

### | Page 2 -  []1 []2 []3 []4 |

Comment: I made some changes and I am closer to the goal. Almost there if anyone can help... Here is what I have  

<!-- language: lang-php -->
    for($x = 1; $x <= $pages; $x++) :
      print "<td id='page_$x' class='page_button' align='center' custom='0' >Page $x - ";
        for($i = 1; $i <= $size; $i++) :
          print "<input type='checkbox' class='ebutton' id='etype_$x' name='checks[]' value='$i' /> $i";
        endfor;

Answer (score 0):

the name should have the different number, the name being sent in the form it should be unique just like your id.

try to set the name like the id : `name='etype_$x'`

and then using the debug console (if using chrome hit f12) then go to network and visualize what variables and values being sent within the form.

Comment: I need the i values, I am able to get the x

Comment: Then you can use $i instead of $x like below:
`name='etype_$i'`
and it all depends on what your needs are, you can even use both of them :
`name='etype_$x_$i'`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $editions = $("#page_"+page_num+" input[checked=checked]");
var editions = [];
$editions.each(function(input) {
  editions.push($(input).val());
});
```

Comment: Ed - This is a popup window that allows the user to select what editions are going to be valid for each page. The number of editions is a value that is stored in a MYSQL database.  I have been able to set the page number as the id of the checkboxlist and pull that, but I am having issues getting the checkboxes checked.  I am then using javascript to get the values and pass them back to the original page.  The values that are sent back are page: _x_ values _checks[]_.

Comment: I have created a Fiddle page that has the problem in it if anyone can assist. Its an HTML table with 2 rows of checkboxes. I need to get the checked data per row, and all I can figure out is how to get all checked values... Here is the link if someone can assist: [j-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RevPhil/yqh3x/)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need javascript to send the checkboxes to a php

You can name the checks like `checks[$page][]`:

```
print "<input type='checkbox' class='ebutton' id='etype_$x' name='checks[$x][]' value='$i' /> $i";
```

and in your action page you will have in $_POST(pr $_GET)["checks"][1] an array with the values checked for the page 1 (if any)

Comment: I am using JavaScript because i have not action page or post variables. This is a popup window and i am returning these selected variables to the previous page.

Comment: ahh ok, you may put this in the question... i'm giving you other answer

Comment: I have created a Fiddle page that has the problem in it if anyone can assist. Its an HTML table with 2 rows of checkboxes. I need to get the checked data per row, and all I can figure out is how to get all checked values... Here is the link if someone can assist:   [j_fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RevPhil/yqh3x/)

Comment: I changed the php to 

<input type='checkbox' class='ebutton' id='etype_[$x]' name='checks[]' value='0$i'/>

and added this for the java:
// get editions checked /
var editions='';
document.getElementById("editions").style.visibility="visible";
var elements = document.getElementById("myform").elements;
 for(var i=0; i< elements.length;i++){
  if(elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && elements[i].checked)
    editions = elements[i].value ;
  }

My results are now: 
page:1 value:01
page:2 value:01
page:2 value:02
 
How can I combine the like pages and values
 page:1 value:01
 page:2 value:01,02

Answer (score 0):

Now, Knowing it is a popup windows who sends to parent the checks...

Make the checks like:

```
print "<input type='checkbox' class='ebutton checks$x' id='etype_$x' name='checks".$x."[]' value='$i' /> $i";
```

to get the class of checks of the page 1 as "checks1", the class of page 2 checks like "checks2", ...

And to get the checked ones:

```
 var page_num = idp[1];
 var checks=$('checks'+page_num).attr('checked',true); //to get all checked checkboxes of the class checks+page_num
 var editions="";
 checks.each(function(ch) {
     editions+=$(ch).val()+',';
 }
```

and editions has all the checked values of that page separated by ','

Comment: I had to change add a **)** at the end, but this still is not getting the desired result. I am still having the same issue. examples: I have Page 1 []01 []02 and Page 2 []01 []02. I select both 01 and 02 for page 1 and only 01 for page 2. My results are Page:1 Values: 01 Page:2 Values: 01,02,01

Comment: I made some changes and I am closer to the goal. Almost there if anyone can help... Here is what I have